# Deploy ComputeJob on IgniteCompute

Tags: ignite

1st question: could I deploy a [`ComputeJob`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/compute/ComputeJob.html) to every node on [`IgniteCompute`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCompute.html)?

I know Ignite can deploy [`ComputeTask`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/compute/ComputeTask.html) which is made up of `ComputeJob`s. After I checked the internal code, it seems to me that `ComputeJob` is serialzied, sent together with args to the remote code, and then processed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

In my case, one node will load a locally deployed copy of the `ComputeTask` and then `ComputeTask` will spawn `ComputeJob`s which are sent to other nodes for computation. These `ComputeJob`s spawned are all same except the args passed to it. In this case, if I could load a locally deployed copy of `ComputeJob` on the remote node and pass only the args that sent to this node through network, the network communication should decrease. The theoretical bottleneck of my application is network bandwith, which I am trying to optimize.

2nd question: if I could not deploy a `ComputeJob`, is there any workaround to prevent sending same `ComputeJob` multiple times?

Thanks a lot for your insight!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! General note: it is better to separate your questions than list them in the same post. See this question for some details https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts.

Answer (score 0):

When `ComputeJob` is serialized using Ignite's `BinaryMarshaller` it will not carry much overhead. You will not be sending the job's class bytes every time. Binary representation also doesn't contain any field names or other info that can be inferred from the class. Almost all of the bytes will be the actual values of your job's fields which usually correspond to the job arguments. You can find more on the Ignite's binary format [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller).

If you want to take a look at the size and structure of your job's binary form, you can serialize it manually with something like

```
byte[] array = ignite.configuration().getMarshaller().marshal(job);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! The size of overhead of ComputeJob is a relative sense I think. In my case, the args of each ComputeJob have only 16 byte, and I am worried that the overhead of serialized job is relatively large.

Comment: Well, my point is that what you have with `BinaryMarshaller` is basically as small overhead as you can possibly. Also, you can't just put your 16 bytes to the Ethernet link - you have overhead from all network levels - Ethernet, IP, TCP, etc. You'll have not less than 64 bytes overhead just from these three protocols (and probably more). My advice would be not to worry about "wasting" the network capacity on the binary object headers - I can hardly imagine a system where it could be an issue.